# Error in dataView

Tags: android

I am learning to develop apps for android from a book and after following the instructions I end up with the following.

```
private void setStartUpScreenText(){
    TextView planetNameValue =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView1);
    planetNameValue.setText(earth.planetName);
```

I get wavy red underline under the dataView1 in findViewById(). Eclipse informs that dataView1 cannot be resolved or is not a field.

The complete code look like this and i get wavy red underline under all dataView. It says nothing about this error in the book.

```
private void setStartUpScreenText(){
    TextView planetNameValue =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView1);
    planetNameValue.setText(earth.planetName);
    TextView planetMassValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView2);
    planetMassValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetMass));
    TextView planetGravityValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView3);
    planetGravityValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetGravity));
    TextView planetColoniesValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView4);
    planetColoniesValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetColonies));
    TextView planetPopulationValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView5);
    planetPopulationValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetPopulation));
    TextView planetMilitaryValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView6);
    planetMilitaryValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetMilitary));
    TextView planetBasesValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView7);
    planetBasesValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetBases));
    TextView planetForceFieldValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView8);
    planetForceFieldValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetProtection));
```

Here the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
WorldGen earth = new WorldGen("Earth", 5973, 9.78);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
    setStartUpWorldValue();
    setStartUpScreenText();
}

protected void setStartUpWorldValue(){
    earth.setPlanetColonies(1);
    earth.setPlanetMilitary(1);
    earth.setColonyImmigration(1000);
    earth.setBaseProtection(100);
    earth.turnForceFieldOn();

}

private void setStartUpScreenText(){
    TextView planetNameValue =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView1);
    planetNameValue.setText(earth.planetName);
    TextView planetMassValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView2);
    planetMassValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetMass));
    TextView planetGravityValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView3);
    planetGravityValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetGravity));
    TextView planetColoniesValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView4);
    planetColoniesValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetColonies));
    TextView planetPopulationValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView5);
    planetPopulationValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetPopulation));
    TextView planetMilitaryValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView6);
    planetMilitaryValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetMilitary));
    TextView planetBasesValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView7);
    planetBasesValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetBases));
    TextView planetForceFieldValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView8);
    planetForceFieldValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetProtection));


}
```

Comment: Have you created `TextView`s in your `activity.xml` with that id? I.E. `<TextView android:id="@+id/dataView1" ..../> `

Comment: If you have declared the Textviews in your xml like @delpes says check that they have been compiled and added to the R Class. And if using eclipse press CTRL + shift +  O to automatically import all classes needed.

Comment: Yes. I put it in fragment_main.xml because the textView and dataView have to be in Relative Layout tags.

Comment: Are you in `onCreateView` method from your fragment when you use `setStartUpScreenText`?

Comment: Thanks @algui91 and Delpes for the respond. The error has gone but i can't run it on emulator. The emulator just blinking and nothing was shown. I call the setStartUpWorldValue() and setStartUpScreenText() method in the onCreate() method.

Comment: I don't understand clearly. You use the `fragment_main.xml` inside your Activity? Do you have a fragment or a FragmentTransaction inside `onCreate` from your activity?

Comment: I can't understand what you asking @Fllo.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to rewrite: you said that you "put it in fragment_main.xml" and I'd know if you use this layout inside `setContentView(*here*)`? Also, I'd like to know if you have any fragment in your activity (because *fragment_main.xml* is the name of a fragment's layout when you create a new project)? Am I clear? :)

Comment: No. I make the textView tags in my fragment_main.xml in the layout folder. I make the setStartUpScreenText method in MainActivity.

Comment: Could you edit your post with your activity please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you built your views inside **fragment_main.xml** and not **activity_main.xml**.

When you *first* create a new android project, you have these files which are automatically created and opened:

[image]

Then, when you begin, you add views *(e.g: a TextView)* inside `fragment_main.xml` file. Finally, you tried to do a basically event with this view inside your `Activity`, something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // Using layout activity_main.xml

        // You try to set a simple text on the view (TextView) previously added
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText("Simple Text");  // And you get an error here!

        /*
         * You do an fragment transaction to add PlaceholderFragment Fragment
         * on screen - this below snippnet is automatically created.
        */
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
```

You cannot run your app or sometimes you have only a white screen, because the views that you tried to call/display are into the wrong layout..

> Solution: **Move all your stuff inside onCreateView method into the Fragment class**.

**Call views and do something in the related fragment and not the parent activity**.

---

Or you can do all inside the activity, by removing these lines which to not add a fragment on your UI:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

This above create and add a fragment "above" your activity layout. And then, setting the right layout here:

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

Comment: No, the emulator said it stopped.

Comment: I add setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main); and its working. Thak you for your help.

Comment: @HazimGharib If this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.